# SMBD Unexpected[???] termination

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, samba4

### Environment

- Server Ubuntu 16.* (x64)
- smbd version 4.7.1
- SMB Client, Explorer @ Windows 10

### Use-case

Browse shared folder ( simple )

### Problem at hand

A while after successfully browsing the folder the SMB client logs off and the SMB server exit(0) w/ errno = 104 ( connection reset )

**Why does the SMB client LOGOFF ???** Is this the expected behavior? Is there any client side session timeout? and, if so, why does SMBD shuts down?

### Diagnostic info bellow:

1. smbd log
2. smb.conf
3. Microsoft Network Monitor dump

### smbd log:

```
smbd version 4.7.1 started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2017
Registered MSG_REQ_POOL_USAGE
Registered MSG_REQ_DMALLOC_MARK and LOG_CHANGED
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[global]"
Processing section "[AWSVFS]"
adding IPC service
added interface docker0 ip=172.17.0.1 bcast=172.17.255.255 netmask=255.255.0.0
added interface eth0 ip=192.168.10.94 bcast=192.168.10.255 netmask=255.255.255.0
loaded services
INFO: Profiling support unavailable in this build.
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2'. Symbols loaded.
Failed to fetch domain sid for WORKGROUP
Failed to fetch domain sid for WORKGROUP
Initialise the svcctl registry keys if needed.
Initialise the eventlog registry keys if needed.
reloading printcap cache
reload status: ok
reloading printcap cache
reload status: ok
waiting for connections
Allowed connection from 192.168.10.71 (192.168.10.71)
init_oplocks: initializing messages.
Transaction 0 of length 159 (0 toread)
switch message SMBnegprot (pid 26793) conn 0x0
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM850.so
Loaded '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/IBM850.so'. Symbols loaded.
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/UTF-16.so
Loaded '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/UTF-16.so'. Symbols loaded.
Requested protocol [PC NETWORK PROGRAM 1.0]
Requested protocol [LANMAN1.0]
Requested protocol [Windows for Workgroups 3.1a]
Requested protocol [LM1.2X002]
Requested protocol [LANMAN2.1]
Requested protocol [NT LM 0.12]
Requested protocol [SMB 2.002]
Requested protocol [SMB 2.???]
Selected protocol SMB2_FF
Stopped due to shared library event (no libraries added or removed)
Stopped due to shared library event:
  Inferior loaded /usr/local/samba/lib/gensec/krb5.so
Loaded '/usr/local/samba/lib/gensec/krb5.so'. Symbols loaded.
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
Selected protocol SMB 2.???
Selected protocol SMB3_11
Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0xe2088297
Got user=[noone] domain=[NRUBIN0470-CPC] workstation=[NRUBIN0470-CPC] len1=24 len2=260
lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
Initialising global parameters
Processing section "[global]"
Processing section "[AWSVFS]"
adding IPC service
check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [NRUBIN0470-CPC]\[noone]@[NRUBIN0470-CPC] with the new password interface
check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [NRUBIN0470-CPC]\[noone]@[NRUBIN0470-CPC]
check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'noone' in passdb.
check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [noone] -> [noone] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER, authoritative=1
Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [NRUBIN0470-CPC]\[noone] at [×‘', 22 ×™× ×• 2018 08:10:03.076238 GMT] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER] workstation [NRUBIN0470-CPC] remote host [ipv4:192.168.10.71:52554] mapped to [NRUBIN0470-CPC]\[noone]. local host [ipv4:192.168.10.94:445]
log_no_json: JSON auth logs not available unless compiled with jansson
No such user noone [NRUBIN0470-CPC] - using guest account
Allowed connection from 192.168.10.71 (192.168.10.71)
Connect path is '/tmp' for service [IPC$]
Initialising default vfs hooks
Initialising custom vfs hooks from [/[Default VFS]/]
nrubin0470-cpc (ipv4:192.168.10.71:52554) connect to service IPC$ initially as user nobody (uid=65534, gid=65534) (pid 26793)
api_pipe_bind_req: wkssvc -> wkssvc rpc service
check_bind_req for wkssvc context_id=0
check_bind_req: wkssvc -> wkssvc rpc service
api_rpcTNP: rpc command: WKSSVC_NETWKSTAGETINFO
api_pipe_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
check_bind_req for srvsvc context_id=0
check_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
api_rpcTNP: rpc command: SRVSVC_NETSRVGETINFO
api_pipe_bind_req: wkssvc -> wkssvc rpc service
check_bind_req for wkssvc context_id=0
check_bind_req: wkssvc -> wkssvc rpc service
api_rpcTNP: rpc command: WKSSVC_NETWKSTAGETINFO
api_pipe_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
check_bind_req for srvsvc context_id=0
check_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
api_rpcTNP: rpc command: SRVSVC_NETSRVGETINFO
api_pipe_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
check_bind_req for srvsvc context_id=0
check_bind_req: srvsvc -> srvsvc rpc service
api_rpcTNP: rpc command: SRVSVC_NETSHAREENUMALL
nrubin0470-cpc (ipv4:192.168.10.71:52554) closed connection to service IPC$
```

### smb.conf:

```
[global]
    map to guest = Bad User
    guest account = nobody
    guest only = yes
    log file = /var/log/samba/%m
    log level = 3

[AWSVFS]
    comment = AWS VFS module
    path = /home/noone/share
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
```

### Microsoft Network Monitor dump

```
3.8737777   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   WKST    WKST:NetrWkstaGetInfo Response, ReturnValue=0   {MSRPC:21, SMB2:20, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8738624   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SMB2    SMB2:C   CLOSE (0x6), FID=0xA3ABB877(wkssvc@#669)   {SMB2:20, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8740914   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SMB2    SMB2:R   CLOSE (0x6), File=wkssvc@#669      {SMB2:20, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8743103   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SMB2    SMB2:C   CREATE (0x5), Sh(RWD), File=srvsvc@#685    {SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8746416   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SMB2    SMB2:R   CREATE (0x5), FID=0xAF9A7796(srvsvc@#685)  {SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8747049   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SMB2    SMB2:C   QUERY INFORMATION (0x10), Class=FileStandardInformation (5), FID=0xAF9A7796(srvsvc@#685)   {SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8749316   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SMB2    SMB2:R   QUERY INFORMATION (0x10), File=srvsvc@#685     {SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8750026   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   MSRPC   MSRPC:c/o Bind: srvs(SRVS) UUID{4B324FC8-1670-01D3-1278-5A47BF6EE188}  Call=0x2  Assoc Grp=0x0  Xmit=0x10B8  Recv=0x10B8    {MSRPC:23, SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8752435   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SMB2    SMB2:R   WRITE (0x9), File=srvsvc@#685  {SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8752999   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SMB2    SMB2:C   READ (0x8), FID=0xAF9A7796  (srvsvc@#685) , 0x400 bytes from offset 0 (0x0)    {SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8756303   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   MSRPC   MSRPC:c/o Bind Ack:  Call=0x2  Assoc Grp=0x53F0  Xmit=0x10B8  Recv=0x10B8   {MSRPC:23, SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8756988   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SRVS    SRVS:NetrServerGetInfo Request, ServerName=\\192.168.10.94 Level=101    {MSRPC:23, SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8760791   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SRVS    SRVS:NetrServerGetInfo Response, Status=ERROR_SUCCESS   {MSRPC:23, SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8761586   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SMB2    SMB2:C   CLOSE (0x6), FID=0xAF9A7796(srvsvc@#685)   {SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.8764261   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SMB2    SMB2:R   CLOSE (0x6), File=srvsvc@#685      {SMB2:22, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9533802   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SMB2    SMB2:C   CREATE (0x5), Sh(RWD), File=srvsvc@#701    {SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9537679   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SMB2    SMB2:R   CREATE (0x5), FID=0x4FB4666E(srvsvc@#701)  {SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9538780   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SMB2    SMB2:C   QUERY INFORMATION (0x10), Class=FileStandardInformation (5), FID=0x4FB4666E(srvsvc@#701)   {SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9541882   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SMB2    SMB2:R   QUERY INFORMATION (0x10), File=srvsvc@#701     {SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9542911   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   MSRPC   MSRPC:c/o Bind: srvs(SRVS) UUID{4B324FC8-1670-01D3-1278-5A47BF6EE188}  Call=0x2  Assoc Grp=0x0  Xmit=0x10B8  Recv=0x10B8    {MSRPC:25, SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9546555   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SMB2    SMB2:R   WRITE (0x9), File=srvsvc@#701  {SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9547453   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SMB2    SMB2:C   READ (0x8), FID=0x4FB4666E  (srvsvc@#701) , 0x400 bytes from offset 0 (0x0)    {SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9551359   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   MSRPC   MSRPC:c/o Bind Ack:  Call=0x2  Assoc Grp=0x53F0  Xmit=0x10B8  Recv=0x10B8   {MSRPC:25, SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9552194   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SRVS    SRVS:NetrShareEnum Request, ServerName=\\192.168.10.94 PreferedMaximumLength=4294967295 ResumeHandle=NULL   {MSRPC:25, SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9557021   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SRVS    SRVS:NetrShareEnum Response, TotalEntries=3 ResumeHandle=NULL Status=ERROR_SUCCESS  {MSRPC:25, SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9558167   192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SMB2    SMB2:C   CLOSE (0x6), FID=0x4FB4666E(srvsvc@#701)   {SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
3.9561380   192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SMB2    SMB2:R   CLOSE (0x6), File=srvsvc@#701      {SMB2:24, SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
14.5760160  192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SMB2    SMB2:C   TREE DISCONNECT (0x4), TID=0xe5211280  {SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
14.5765348  192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SMB2    SMB2:R   TREE DISCONNECT (0x4)  {SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
14.5766266  192.168.10.71   192.168.10.94   SMB2    SMB2:C   LOGOFF (0x2)   {SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
14.5771544  192.168.10.94   192.168.10.71   SMB2    SMB2:R   LOGOFF (0x2)   {SMBOverTCP:16, TCP:15, IPv4:35}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe I am searching for this same issue. Windows 10 (and Server 2016) disallow guest access by default. This should lead you in the right direction.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4046019/guest-access-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-server-2016

The link above reads, and I had to make this setting to get it to work:

> If you want to enable insecure guest access, you can configure the following Group Policy settings:
>
> Computer configuration\administrative templates\network\Lanman Workstation "Enable insecure guest logons"
>
> Note By enabling insecure guest logons, this setting reduces the security of Windows clients.

By default, Windows doesn't allow guest access to server shares since Windows 2000.

Comment: Link only answers should not be posted at Server Fault, as they often become stale and therefore useless. You should edit the answer to actually _include_ an _answer_.